# Altitude of a place given Latitude and longitude?

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

Is there a way I could find altitude of a place, given its latitude- and longitude- ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/elevation/

Comment: From usage terms: The Elevation API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using elevation data without displaying a map for which elevation data was requested is prohibited.